# How can I count the max amount of numbers, which are increasing in a row by date in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, counter

My goal is to get the count of the max amount of numbers, which are increasing in a row in a certain date range. Below is an array. The correct answer of the max amount increasing numbers between 01/13/2021 and 02/17/2021 would be 5 as the numbers 3,8,10,13,15 are growing in that date range.

I managed to search in a certain period of time...

```
$row = array(
  array('01/02/2021', 1),
  array('01/13/2021', 4),
  array('01/15/2021', 6),
  array('01/19/2021', 9),
  array('01/30/2021', 5),
  array('02/03/2021', 4),
  array('02/11/2021', 3),
  array('02/12/2021', 8),
  array('02/15/2021', 10),
  array('02/16/2021', 13),
  array('02/17/2021', 15),
  array('02/18/2021', 16)
);

$startDateNew = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("2021-01-13"));
$endDateNew = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("2021-02-17"));
foreach($row as $x) {
  if(($x[0]>=$startDateNew)&&($x[0]<=$endDateNew) ){
    echo 'Found ';
    print_r($x);
  }
}
```

I managed also to search the first increasing number sequence in a one-dimensional array as the answer of the code below is 4. But I didn't succeed to continue this search after if-sentence to the next increasing sequence(and the next and the next), so that the correct answer would be 5 in this case.

Including to that, these two searches should combine somehow together.

```
$numbers = array(1,4,6,9,5,4,3,8,10,13,15);

function LCIS($numbers) {
  $counter = 1; 
  $answer = 1; 
  for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers) -1; $i++) { //
    if ($numbers[$i] < $numbers[$i+1]) { //comparing array indexes together
      $counter++; //
      $answer = max($answer, $counter); //this doesn't do anything spectacular right now...
      continue; 
    }else {
      $counter == 1; 
    }
    return $answer;
  }
}

echo LCIS($numbers);
```

I'm very beginner at php coding. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have already 2 parts of the code you just need to combine them together. What I suggest is to feed the `$numbers` array during checking if the `$row` array element is in certain date range.

```
function LCIS($numbers)
{
    $counter = 1;
    $answer = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers) - 1; $i++) { //
        if ($numbers[$i] < $numbers[$i + 1]) { //comparing array indexes together
            $counter++; //
            $answer = max($answer, $counter); //this doesn't do anything spectacular right now...
        } else {
            $counter = 1;
        }

    }
    return $answer;
}

$row = array(
    array('01/02/2021', 1),
    array('01/13/2021', 4),
    array('01/15/2021', 6),
    array('01/19/2021', 9),
    array('01/30/2021', 5),
    array('02/03/2021', 4),
    array('02/11/2021', 3),
    array('02/12/2021', 8),
    array('02/15/2021', 10),
    array('02/16/2021', 13),
    array('02/17/2021', 15),
    array('02/18/2021', 16)
);

$numbers = array();
$startDateNew = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("2021-01-13"));
$endDateNew = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("2021-02-17"));
foreach($row as $x) {
    if(($x[0]>=$startDateNew)&&($x[0]<=$endDateNew) ){
        $numbers[] = $x[1];
    }
}

echo LCIS($numbers);
```

BTW: I have modified a little your `LCIS` function and it will run faster and more correct.

Comment: wow! thanks! much closer to the answer. There's still some mystery with the answer. In this particular date range, the answer should be 5, now it's 6. When changing the $endDateNew to '2021-02-11', the answer is 2 (should be 3).  And when the endDateNew is '2021-02-15', the answer is 4 (should be 3).

Comment: @kaaritz sorry but I don't understand, In the date range 2021-01-13 and 2021-02-11 the "positive" values are 4=>6, 6=>9. the same situation is with other date ranges. So maybe the logic of your `LCIS` function is wrong?

Comment: Okay, maybe needs a little bit clarification! Maybe the word LCIS is not the right term for this. So I'd like to know how many times the numbers are growing.In the date range 2021-01-13 and 2021-02-11.
Here the numbers are growing 3 times:
1. array('01/13/2021', 4),
2. array('01/15/2021', 6),
3. array('01/19/2021', 9),
Here they grow 5 times: 
array
1.('02/11/2021', 3),
2.array('02/12/2021', 8),
3. array('02/15/2021', 10),
4.array('02/16/2021', 13),
5.array('02/17/2021', 15),
And the answer what I'm looking for, is that max time, so 5 times in this case.

Comment: ok then can you tell me what should be the answer for the period from 2021--01-30 and 2021-02-11?

Comment: @zeusam Then the answer should be only 1, cause the numbers arent' rising at all.

Comment: @kaaritz ok I got the point and updated the code, please have a look

Comment: Yes! Now it's exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: If you mean the voting, I did that, but there came a note: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. :)